# Inner grid lines in whole WPF ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, listview

I need to implement the following design in my classic Windows WPF application (expected):

[image: Expected]

I use WPF ListView control and already implemented many needed features, but I can’t exactly realize the designer’s vision. At the moment my control looks like the following schema (actual):

[image: Actual]

It has two drawbacks:

1. Grid lines placed inside and outside of cells, but the initial style provides inner lines only.
2. Grid lines extend on filled rows only, but I need to fill all control area, even empty (unused) space.

Could anyone help me to solve those problems? Maybe I need to use another WPF control?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to write a custom `Style` for your `ListView`. Have a look at this site: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/09/21/how-to-insert-row-divider-lines-in-a-wpf-listview.aspx

Comment: Thank you, @DominicJonas. I've read this article. But this approach with negative margins can be used for drawing vertical or horizontal lines only. But it doesn't resolve both my issues - hide outer grid lines and cover whole control including free space (when short collections used).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if `ListView` is the right `Control` for your conditions. Maybe `GridView` or a `DataGrid` is a better decision.

Here is a modified version of the default `styles` of `ListView` and `ListViewItem`. Take this part of the snippet and extend it for your needs.

#### Style

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Changes:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
```

#### XAML

```
    <ListView VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}">
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

#### Preview

[image]

Comment: I tried to use your code - [link](https://github.com/sotnyk/wpf-listview-innergridline)

But this approach doesn't solve both of my tasks: all cells have equal borders (it should be different in the first, middle and the last column).

`<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>` means that all borders are the same. 

And the free from rows control area remains without grid lines.

Sorry, but I can't use this solution.

Comment: Just setting `BorderThickness` is not all the way. Styling a `DataGrid` is very complex and the link should give you an entry how to do it. The following link also helped me a lot to understand: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/01/20/styling-microsofts-wpf-datagrid/
A very quick and dirty solution would be to style your template that you have the lines everywhere and inside of the `DataGrid` `Template` (in the `Style`) set `Margin="-1"`. So the outer border is trimmed.